# sql ignore days in the week with datefirst

Tags: sql-server

I am working in a algorithm that needs to be calculated based on the number of working days.

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Holidays
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Holidays VALUES ('2019-07-16', '2019-07-17')






DECLARE @CurrentWeekDay INT

SET DATEFIRST 1
// Returns day of the week as int, ex... Monday = 0, Tue = 1....
SET @CurrentWeekDay = DATEPART (WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1
```

this starts on Monday until Friday, 0,1,2,3,4, which is subtracted on the total days of the week

Now i have created 2 new variables

```
DECLARE @TotalHolidays INT, @IsSameWeek BIT

    // If there is a holiday in the current week get the holiday date, else just cast 0
    SET @IsSameWeek = 
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK,GETDATE(), (SELECT TOP 1 EndDate FROM Holidays))) = -1 THEN 0
        ELSE 
            1
        END 

    SET @TotalHolidays = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @IsSameWeek = 1 THEN (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate ) FROM Holidays)
        ELSE 
            0
        END
```

so basically the total amount of days left in the week is calculated using this simple formula

```
DECLARE @TotalDays = 5,
SET @TotalDays = @TotalDays - @TotalHolidays - @CurrentWeekDay
```

this is all nice but this is only effective when the holidays start at the end of the week.

```
Datefirst
M T W T F
0 1 2 3 4
```

if Thursday and friday are holidays the algorithm works nicely, but if Wednesday is a holiday then it ruins everything

basically i need it so if wednesday is a holiday

Datefirst goes like

```
M T W T F
0 1   2 3
```

With all set this is the whole code

```
CREATE TABLE Holidays
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Holidays VALUES ('2019-07-18', '2019-07-19')

DECLARE @TotalHolidays INT, @IsSameWeek BIT, @CurrentWeekDay INT

SET DATEFIRST 1
SET @CurrentWeekDay = DATEPART (WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1 


    SET @IsSameWeek = 
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK,GETDATE(), (SELECT TOP 1 EndDate FROM Holidays))) = -1 THEN 0
        ELSE 
            1
        END 

    SET @TotalHolidays = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @IsSameWeek = 1 THEN (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate ) FROM Holidays)
        ELSE 
            0
        END



DECLARE @DaysLeft INT

SET @DaysLeft = 5 - @TotalHolidays - @CurrentWeekDay
```

This will return 0 when it should return 2

Comment: Your example isnt clear. What is the value of the variables?. What is the current day? What result you expect? What is the logic for @TotalHolidays ?

Comment: Variables `@TotalHolidays INT, @IsSameWeek BIT` seem to return the same value everytime,  there isnt a different variable affecting the calculation

Comment: added some comments to explain

Comment: As I said you need to provide more data. I dont know what day is what week is or what holidays are there.

Comment: The value of total holidays is based on a specific start, end date total number of days. it can be any given date

Comment: added whole code at the end, should be enough to test

Comment: it is returning 1, your code

Comment: Might have to do with Datefirst due to different timezones, monday is supposed to be 0, hence why -1 at the end so the total days in the first day is intact

Comment: Since you have a `Holidays` table, why not just also have a `Calendar` table as well ?

Comment: That requires time to implement and my application is due for testing tomorrow and this is the only problem left. Although i had some idea in minds by creating a  table just to hold each day of the week. The holidays are set by the users since holidays only need to be checked on current week

Comment: According to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. It still sees Sunday as the first day of the week. You might look there for your problem